# og:title, description and image

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

i'm currently going a thumbnails generator for my site and maybe other people can use it so what this does is to generate a html file and that file get instant uploaded to the webhost so the file looks like the following code but the issue that facebook saying they didn't detect the og: title and description and image ... weird maybe i'm doing something wrong or the code is wrong ?

Just to note i use the facebook debug to scrape it and check : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="John.Evenetcha"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="2217370698541973"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="ar_AR">
<title> تيار المحبة </title>
<meta name="description" content="القيادي بحزب تيار المحبة حسام الهمادي ينفي اشاعة التحالف مع نداء تونس ويصفها"> 
<meta name="Keywords" content="Tayar Al Mahaba" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/John.Evenetcha" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/John.Evenetcha" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="تيار المحبة"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent.ftun2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/44410830_2120345971363361_6384115955156385792_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_ht=scontent.ftun2-1.fna&oh=246eea65cc7fddd40108f6bd8f840876&oe=5C52445D"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="تيار المحبة"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="القيادي بحزب تيار المحبة حسام الهمادي ينفي اشاعة التحالف مع نداء تونس ويصفها"/>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=https://tayar-al-mahaba.cf/TAM/news/view/9">
<BODY>
Redirecting...
</BODY>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure those characters used are supported by UTF-8?

Comment: I'm not sure :/ that's the issue and actually the generator is vb.net application and i used : System.Text.Encoding.Unicode

Comment: Solved the issue ! HTML is good i just removed system.text.encoding.unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue! the problem was that i generate it using VB.NET and got System.Text.Encoding.Unicode in the rewrite method i though that will make it good :D